# How to use Deep Reinforcement Learning with a Snake Game

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

Ideally I want to use a neural network using a deep reinforcement learning method. However I don’t want to gather data from initially running the game like 1000 times for instance, and then use that data to feed the neural network (that would be supervised learning?). I would rather prefer to use a deep reinforcement learning method (with neural networks). I have looked into Q-learning which seems great and all, and could kind of work. However the main problem with Q-learning is that the apple (food) on the snake board will always spawn in random locations (non-deterministic), so if I find an optimal policy (using q-learning), it won’t work when the food re-spawns in a different location (would need to learn the policy over again).

Also, I was thinking of ideally not using evolutionary algorithms neither. Is there like a pure ’base’-method (RL) to ‘teach’ the snake-agent to get rewarded for getting closer to a food-item (for example using back propagation), without gathering a bunch of pre-run-games to then feed the network, nor to use neither Q-learning nor evolutionary algorithms? It seems like all resources I have found use one of these, which is not what I want.

[Architecture Idea. input_left=3, input_front=-1, input_right=-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQKxs.png)

Side note: Could I just feed in a list for each direction the snake can perceive (left, right, forward)? Where each direction-input-list holds for example: [0, 5], where the first number is either food (1) or wall (0), and the second number is the distance to that object. This input-list will be fed in as shown in the picture. I guess I also could just rely on a single int per input, being -1, if there is a wall or itself, and if it is an apple I just give the distance to the apple (front, left or right for the snake).

Now my question is: Is Tensorflow able to just do some magic to find the best function (having the TF-model already set-up), using this technique to feed through the model? Is there not a way the neural network must do the whole back propagation thing in regards to the reward/feedback it gets in terms of how well it did (for example: it got closer to the apple, so it gets a small reward, but minus a tiny penalty for taking one step)… All these functions are easy to implement, but I guess the problem is with the back-propagation part (which I don’t understand perfectly). I understand that the network (if it gets a positive reward) will tweak the fired weights upwards, and leave the others as is (randomly initialised?)… is that correct and is Tensorflow/Keras able to deal with this?

Not sure if this architecture makes sense and if it could work.

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: Why not feed it with the location of the apple as well?

Comment: well I guess you could argue that that would not be '"fair" as the snake is in a 2D simulation and can only 'see' from its perspective...

Comment: Fair enough, you could give the distance from the snake, or that's what you meant as input right=3,left=2 etc..?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, now I've understood what your asking, your saying that the distance from the next apple changes and therefor could indicate that the model has set the snake in the wrong direction?

Comment: Oh, I just edited it now. But no - I actually meant: input_left=3, input_front=-1, input_right=-1 (wrong in image). I was just thinking: it does not matter (I suppose) to know a distance to something you would want to avoid anyways? If that does not work, I suppose the [apple/not-apple(1/-1), distance (if apple)] could work too...

Comment: Oh, I was not thinking about the "direction" of the snake at all tbh. I guess the model is only seeing from the snake's head/eyes anyways, and don't really care about the rest of the body. So it "knows" the "direction" the snake is going in... Note: the apple only respawns if it eats it. (same rules as classic snake game)

Comment: Got it, check out - https://github.com/chuyangliu/snake/blob/master/docs/algorithms.md#dqn-solver

Comment: It uses Deep Q-Network to solve it like you've asked, look at the implementation that will set you off to a good start